# merge a few lists and regroup them into a dictionary to plot to multi-series Highcharts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, highcharts

```
animal = ['Hamster', 'Dolphin', 'Ant', 'Hamster', 'Hamster', 'Ant']
date = [20151007, 20151007, 20151007, 20141007, 20120101, 20010101]
total = [27, 5, 5, 5, 18, 40]
```

I want to combine these 3 list into one. But if the animal is the same, it should be grouped together and the total should follow asc date. If the animal type doesn't have enough date, it'll become 0. For example:

```
[{'name': 'Hamster', 'data': [0, 18, 5, 27]}, 
{'name': 'Dolphin', 'data': [0, 0, 0, 5]}, 
{'name': 'Ant', 'data': [40, 0, 0, 5]}]
```

I'm trying to plot them to Highcharts
The dates are in its own list.

```
[20010101, 20120101, 20141007, 20151007]
```

I can combine the lists together using:

```
zip(animal, date, total)
```

but how to get them into it's own type and arrange the total by asc date?

### edited

This is how I got so far. 
I don't think it's efficient.
What do you think? Any improvement to suggest? (Only pythonic suggestion pls)

```
b = []
for k, v in enumerate(animal):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(b)):
        try:
            if b[i]['name'] == v:
                b[i]['data'].append((date[k], total[k]))
                counter = counter + 1
        except KeyError:
            continue
    if counter == 0:
        b.append({'name': v,  'data': [(date[k], total[k])]})

test = set(date)

for k, v in enumerate(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(animal))):
    for x in test:
        try:
            for i in range(len(test)):
                if b[k]['data'][i][0] == x:
                    break
        except IndexError:
            b[k]['data'].append((x, 0))
    b[k]['data'].sort(key=itemgetter(0))
    temp = [x[1] for x in b[k]['data']]
    b[k]['data'] = []
    b[k]['data'] = temp
```

result:

```
[{'data': [0, 18, 5, 27], 'name': 'Hamster'}, 
{'data': [0, 0, 0, 5], 'name': 'Dolphin'}, 
{'data': [40, 0, 0, 5], 'name': 'Ant'}]
```

Comment: Why `date`s are not there in the expected result?

Comment: what do you mean by *if the animal type doesn't have enough date*?

Comment: some animal (or insect) in the question has only 1 date. The rest has 3 or 2.  I put 0 to fill the gap.

Comment: How exactly did your data get so fragmented?

Comment: loops from django queryset. and I append each of them into its own list.

Comment: @thefourtheye the date is outside of the list. in it's own list. [20010101, 20120101, 20141007,  20151007] they are highcharts format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
animals = ['Hamster', 'Dolphin', 'Ant', 'Hamster', 'Hamster', 'Ant']
dates = [20151007, 20151007, 20151007, 20141007, 20120101, 20010101]
totals = [27, 5, 5, 5, 18, 40]
readings = list(zip(animals, dates, totals))
dates = set(dates)
data = dict()
for animal in animals:
    data[animal] =  {(date, total) for (x, date, total) in readings if x == animal}
    missingDates = dates - {d[0] for d in data[animal] }
    data[animal] |= {(date, 0) for date in missingDates}
```

At this point, `data` is

{'Dolphin': {(20120101, 0), (20151007, 5), (20141007, 0), (20010101, 0)}, 'Hamster': {(20151007, 27), (20141007, 5), (20120101, 18), (20010101, 0)}, 'Ant': {(20120101, 0), (20151007, 5), (20141007, 0), (20010101, 40)}}

and you just need to pull it apart and sort the data for each animal by date.  I hope this helps.

EDIT Here's the further explanation I promised.  Unfortunately I can't see your comment and the edit screen at the same time; I hope I answer all the points you raised.  After zipping the three lists together, we need to extract the data for each animal.  The expression on the right-hand side of

```
data[animal] =  {(date, total) for (x, date, total) in readings if x == animal}
```

is a set comprehension, and it gives us the set of all the (date, total) pairs related a a specific animal.  Now we need to find the missing dates.
I used set difference for this:

```
missingDates = dates - {d[0] for d in data[animal] }
```

This is why I used sets: to be able to write the expression for missing dates succinctly.  Instead, I could have used lists:

```
data[animal] = [(date, total) for (x, date, total) in readings if x == animal]
missingDates = [d for d in dates if d not in [d[0] for d in data[animal]]
```

If I had done this, I wouldn't have needed the earlier statement

```
dates = set(dates)
```

but I wanted to avoid the convoluted expression for missingDates, and I didn't want to write

```
presentDates = [d[0] for d in data[animal] 
missingDates = [d for d in dates if d not in presentDates]
```

Now I have to add the pairs (date, 0) for the missing dates.  If I had used lists, I would write

```
data[animal] += [(date, 0) for date in missingDates]
```

but the `+` operation isn't defined for sets; I need to used union.  (The union of two sets is the set of elements that belong to at least one of the two sets.)  The union operation is represented as`|`.  You're correct that it can represent the bitwise or of two integers, but it can represent other operations as well, just as `+` could mean addition of number or concatenation of lists.  So:

```
data[animal] |= {(date, 0) for date in missingDates}
```

If you're not comfortable with sets, by all means use lists instead, but you should make a point of learning about sets.  They're extremely useful.

To continue past the point I wrote about earlier, you now need to sort data[animal] by date.  Here we would have to change back to lists, because sets are unsorted.

```
data[animal] = list(data[animal])
data[animal].sort()
data[animal] = [d[1] for d in data[animal]]
```

Of course, if you elect to use lists throughout, you don't need the first of these lines.

I hope this clears it up for you.  Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: what is ' |=  '? how significant is this implementation here?

Comment: | is set union. `x |= y` means the same thing as `x = x | y`.  I'm not sure I understand the rest of your question.  There are ways of doing this without using `|=`.  Indeed, you could do it using lists instead of sets, though it would be a bit more verbose.  What is it about `|=` that bothers you?

Comment: sorry if u dont understand my question. I was asking the logic of using bitwise | in the set. I don't quite get how the data is manipulated there. we can translate it to data[animal] = data[animal] or {(date, 0) for date in missingDates} . what is it checking here exactly? how is it data[animal] false then {(date, 0) for date in missingDates} is added to the set?

Comment: It isn't bitwise or.  It's set union.  Give me a few minutes and I'll expand the explanation in my  answer.

Comment: Glad to, but I wasn't the one who downvoted it.  I can't stand downvotes with no explanation.

Comment: i added a variation of my own . for animal in set(animal). this way it'll iterate Hamster and Ant only once.

Comment: Right!  I should have done it this way in the first place.